# Getting crash while executing sample dom-context-item.cpp

Tags: xerces, xqilla

I want to make use of xqilla 2.3.0 in my project.

For this i tried the sample program in dom-context-item.cpp. But a crash "First-chance exception at 0x6b93ad61 (msvcp100d.dll) in XqillaParsing.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000004." appears.

The following code triggers the crash
// Parse an XPath 2 expression
AutoRelease expression(document->createExpression(X("foo/bar/@baz"), 0));

All Additional library and headers path are fine.

Any help would be appreciated
Advance Thanks
RCJ

Answer (score 0):

XQilla 2.3.0 don't have any problem while running with MSVC 2008
But while using it with MSVC 2010 the debug build get crashed at function _Container_base12::_Orphan_all()

More information can be found at 
http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=xqilla-user&max_rows=25&style=nested&viewmonth=201005